# How to link C++ Application with cppkafka

Tags: c++, cmake, apache-kafka

As mentioned in the cppkafka official GitHub in usage section.

If you want to use cppkafka, you'll need to link your application with:

- cppkafka
- rdkafka

I tried to compile example program mentioned in the README.md of the GitHub with

```
gcc -O3 -Wall test.cpp -std=c++11 -lrdkafka -lpthread -lz -lstdc++ -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -lcppkafka
```

It is throwing with following error

```
test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x46): undefined reference to `cppkafka::ConfigurationOption::ConfigurationOption(std::string const&, char const*)'
test.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd9): undefined reference to `cppkafka::Buffer::Buffer(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `How do I compile the CPP program by linking the above the libraries` - What **exactly** is difficult for you? **Compiling** of c++ program? - Take any manual about CMake. **Linking** with the library? See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library).

Comment: I linked the above libraries with -lcppkafka and -lrdkafka 
but the compilation is throwing with an error 
undefined reference to `cppkafka::ConfigurationOption::ConfigurationOption(std::string const&, char const*)'

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and describe that attempt in it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev can you look at the question now and help me to resolve the error

Comment: Oh, you just calls `gcc` for compile your program. Then, why `cmake` tag?

Comment: First I am trying with gcc. If it successfully compiled then I will move it to cmake

Comment: On Stack Overflow *tags*  is what the **question post talks about**; not what do you *want* to use in the future.

Comment: As for the problem itself, it looks like compatibility problem. Make sure that you have built `cppkafka` library with the **same compiler**, as you use for your test application.

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev for your time. I figured out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 option while compiling.
you can simply compile this as following

```
gcc -O3 -Wall test.cpp -std=c++11 -lrdkafka -lpthread -lz -lstdc++ -lcppkafka
```