# How to build and use CppKafka?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am learning CppKafka https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka and want to run simple script

```
// main.cpp
#include <cppkafka/cppkafka.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cppkafka;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}
```

I was reading [How to link C++ Application with cppkafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753605/how-to-link-c-application-with-cppkafka) but it didn't help

My actions (my aim is to build the code with help of cmake)

1 Created CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.2)
project(KafkaExample)

add_executable(my_bin main.cpp)

find_package(CppKafka REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_bin CppKafka::cppkafka)
```

2 Downloaded https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka to the folder on the same level with main.cpp

3 Trying to build

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

I have an error

```
% cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCppKafka.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CppKafka",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CppKafka" with any
  of the following names:

    CppKafkaConfig.cmake
    cppkafka-config.cmake
```

I was trying to build cppkafka library

```
cd cppkafka/build
brew install boost
cmake .. 

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCppKafka.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CppKafka",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CppKafka" with any
  of the following names:

    CppKafkaConfig.cmake
    cppkafka-config.cmake
```

Comment: `find_package` requires you to have built and *installed* the library somewhere first.

Comment: Did you override cppkafka's CMakeLists.txt with yours or something? Line 6 in the repository is an `endif()`.

Comment: no, I am building cppKafka library https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Yes, and I am telling you line 6 is an `endif` statement. The only way your error makes sense is that you overwrote cppkafka's CMakeLists.txt with yours.

Comment: "How to build and use CppKafka?" - Documentation for CppKafka clearly describes how to build it - https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka#compiling - and how to use it - https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka#using. Have you tried to just follow that paragraphs? None of them asks to "Downloaded https://github.com/mfontanini/cppkafka to the folder on the same level with main.cpp".

Comment: and what happened when you tried to do what the error message suggested? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11107541